# Python3 - how to write tarfile to a different directory?

Tags: python, tarfile

I am trying to do a backup of directory in variable target_path to a file assigned in variable archive_name.tar.gz and write that file to a directory other than the current directory. The code below works but places the output in the current working directory.  I can't work out whether there is a way of adding an argument to write the file to a directory specified in variable write_path. Any help appreciated!

with tarfile.open(archive_name+'.tar.gz', mode='w:gz') as archive:

```
archive.add(target_path, recursive=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in the open function. You can either use a relative path for example:

```
with tarfile.open('../test'+'.tar.gz', mode='w:gz') as archive:
    archive.add('test', recursive=True)
```

which makes the tar file in parnet folder or an absolute path like:

```
with tarfile.open('/home/user/Desktop/test'+'.tar.gz', mode='w:gz') as archive:
    archive.add('test', recursive=True)
```